# After installing rpy2 the library for R is pointing to miniconda

Tags: r, rpy2

I was trying to use `rpy2` to interoperate `R` and `python` in `jupyter`. It was just a curiosity experiment.  It is not working due to package imports.

But what is *not* an experiment is to be able to install packages in `R` . I can no longer do so after installing `rpy2`.  The following is happening in `R`:

```
> install.packages('ggplot2')

 .. various errors including 

In file included from /Users/steve/miniconda3/lib/R/include/R.h:50:
/Users/steve/miniconda3/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:317:9: error: no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace
```

Why is `miniconda3` in the picture *at all* here?

Later we see:

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘isoband’
* removing ‘/Users/steve/miniconda3/lib/R/library/isoband’
ERROR: dependency ‘isoband’ is not available for package ‘
```

Why is the `R` library directory now pointed to `miniconda3` ?   How do I get back to the normal R libraries location?

Comment: Check out `?.libPaths`, specifically you might need to set environment variables like R_LIBS or R_LIBS_USER etc.

Comment: It is hard to be sure without knowing more about your environment, but if `miniconda` is here you probably installed R through it. The Docker images for `rpy2` show how to install R+rpy2(+jupyter) without conda on an ubuntu system: https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2-docker